# Deep Clone Oracle Table

Tags: oracle10g

In Oracle is there a way to deep clone a table - i.e. clone the table definition + indexes + triggers + constraints (never mind sequences). I am aware of:

```
create clone_table as 
  select * 
    from table
```

, but it only goes as far as table's fields.

I need to to clone a wide range of tables with plenty of indexes/triggers etc, which I'd like to automate. The solution should work with Oracle 10G, but it'll be 11G only it'll also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dbms_metadata` for this task, especially its function `get_ddl`.

Here's [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS640) and I am sure that you will find plenty of examples on the internet.

Alternatively, depending on your exact requirements, you might succeed with `dbms_datapump` or the more old fashioned `exp` and `imp` utility.